# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'bytes'

Tags: python, runtime-error, typeerror

can anyone help me with this problem of mine? here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time
import Adafruit_DHT
import urllib.request

GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup (13, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(13, 1)


def getSensorData(): 
   humidity, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 22) 
   return (float(humidity), float(temp))

baseURL = 'https://mekatronika15.000webhostapp.com/data.php?api_key=%s'
inputURL= 'https://mekatronika15.000webhostapp.com/admin/tes2.php'
try:

   while True:
      humidity, temp = getSensorData()
      humidity = '%.2f' % humidity
      temp = '%.2f' % temp

      try:
         conn = urllib.request.urlopen(baseURL + "&humidity=%s&temp=%s" % (humidity, temp))
         conn1 = urllib.request.urlopen(inputURL)
         print (conn.read())
         conn.close()
         status1 = conn1.read()
         sleep(20)
      except: 
         print ('exiting.')
        
         print (humidity, temp)

    
      if float(temp) >= status1:
         GPIO.output(13, 0)
            
      elif float(temp) <= status1:
         GPIO.output(13, 1)    
         

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

and the error that it gives:

```
if float(temp) >= (status1):
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'bytes'
```

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with python so I'm stuck, I know that there are many similar questions and answer in this app, I've tried some but I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need to declare a variable before using it, you need to be extra careful when trying to do operations on variables.

The problem is this line `status1 = conn1.read()`
Here, `conn1.read()` returns the content of the webpage, namely the source html as a sequence of bytes (similar to a string). Comparing a number with a sequence of characters is an undefined operation; therefore, python raised an error.

You can design a parser to retrieve the information you need. For example, you can convert the bytes you have into a string using `encode()`. Then `find()` the index of the `status1` that you want. Then you can use substring to get `status1` as a string and finally convert it to a number.

Comment: *"You can design a parser to retrieve the information you need"*, well in this case, it'd probably just be easier for the OP to use a pre-built parser, like the one in the standard library, or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @ChristianDean woo nice! I wasn't aware that python has a built-in parser. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Python is known for coming with the batteries included. In this, however, I've heard BeautifulSoup is the better of the two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

`status1` is coming back as bytes and needs to be formatted.

print(status1) before the sleep or use a debugger to check the value. My guess is that you'll need to unpack the response you got a bit more.

The library `requests` is a wrapper around urllib and is generally a bit more usable so you don't need all these steps.

```
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.json  # probably has what you need
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

The [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) function returns a [`HTTPResponse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection) object:

```
import urllib.request
connection = urllib.request.urlopen("https://stackoverflow.com/")
type(connection) # <class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
```

[The `read` method for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read) `HTTPConnection` objects (which you're calling with the statement `status1 = conn1.read()`), is described in the documentation as follows:

> Reads and returns the response body, **or up to
> the next amt bytes**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

So the reason you're getting a type error is that `HTTPConnection.read` returns `bytes`, which can't be compared with a `float`. You'll need to convert the `bytes` to a `float`. If `conn1.read()` is just returning a number in byte form, you can just use `float(status1)`, but I highly suspect `status1` is a little more complicated in its formatting, so you'll need to do some digging to figure what exactly and how exactly you want to extract data from it.

What you'll probably want to look into an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) to help you extract the data you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll look after the link you've sent!